# How does someone achieve a desired confidence / accuracy when measuring using uncalibrated instrument?

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, sampling, accuracy, calibration

I have an instrument that measures a value.

It is only possible to measure the value once i.e. the experiment can't be repeated (think recording a car's speed as it drives past).

The instrument is not calibrated.

I have access to `n` different instruments, each with their own unknown calibration. I might have 4 or 5.

I expect that each instrument will record the value to within 3% of the actual value. But I do not know this for certain, this is just a guess.

How do I work out how many `n` instruments I need to achieve a desired confidence / accuracy? Is it possible to construct a confidence interval taking into account this unknown? How can the accuracy or inaccuracy from this calibration be represented?

Comment: So, are you saying that you expect each measure to have a variance on the order of 3%, but you don't know how biased each measurement is? That an instrument may be miscalibrated, adding say 10 mph to the velocity, but it will usually be within 3% of the actual speed + 10 mph?

Comment: @dherrera I'm afraid my terminology may be incorrect. I expect that each instrument should produce a result +/- 3% of the actual value, _even though I don't know if that is actually the case / if it is misscalibrated or not_ e.g. a reading of an actual speed of 20mph would be in the range 19.4-20.6mph. Does that make sense? How do I workout how many instruments I would need to make the measurement to achieve a desired confidence overall? Especially if the variance were raised e.g. to 10%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that you have a speed of 20 mph. You will have variability in the measurements of your different devices, and from what you say, you expect each device to be within 3% of the actual value. Let's say then that 3% is the standard deviation of the variability between the different instruments, so the standard deviation between devices is 0.6 mph for your 20 mph real speed. Let's call that standard deviation $\sigma_{device}$.

To solve the problem we next need to make two assumptions:

1. The 'error' of the devices is independent and identically distributed. Regarding independence, this means that we don't expect that on a given measure all devices overestimate or all devices overshoot (or undershoot) at the same time. Regarding identically distributed, this means that we don't expect some devices to be highly flawed and some highly accurate, but rather they all have similar degrees of precision, at least in principle.
2. The errors of the devices are spread around the actual value of speed. That is, it's not the case that all devices always overestimate the speed, but rather some overestimate and some underestimate, by on average the same amount.

These are some typical assumptions.

Then, if on average the devices are correct, even if the individual devices aren't, we can add more devices to get a better estimation of what the true speed is, because their errors will average out more as we add more devices.

How variable is the **average** between the devices, given how variable is each device and how many devices we are averaging? That's just given by the standard deviation of the mean, which is discussed [here](https://sisu.ut.ee/measurement/33-standard-deviation-mean). That is the variability that the average will have, and it is given by:

$$\sigma_{average} = \frac{\sigma_{device}}{\sqrt{N}}$$

where $N$ is the number of devices that you have. So, say that you have 5 devices with a $\sigma_{device} = 0.6$ as described above, then the formula says that the average will have a standard deviation of $\sigma_{average} = 0.268 mph$. In the assumptions above we assumed that the average is centered around the true mean (20 mph), and $\pm 1.96\sigma_{average}$ is the region that will contain 95% of the average estimates, so 95% of your device averages will be within 19.474 and 20.526.

To get to the number of devices needed, you just need to:

1. Pick a reference speed
2. Obtain the corresponding $\sigma_{device}$ that you guess
3. Pick a $\sigma_{average}$ that is acceptable for your purposes
4. Solve for $N$

Your specification of the problem is not clear though, so it's not certain whether this specification will match your actual real problem, but it seems like a standard approach to what you describe. And needless to say, the performance of the method will depend on how good your guess of the % of variance of the devices is, whether they are on average correct, etc. Also, we assumed that 3% is the standard deviation of the devices errors, but maybe this would mean that a given measurement would be within 3% of the true mean only ~62% of the time, which is maybe not what you meant by "I expect that each instrument will record the value to within 3% of the actual value." Statistics is not magic, and if you start from wrong assumptions, you will end up with wrong conclusions.

If this answers your question, please consider marking as the accepted answer.

Comment: Good answer, but I would think that your assumption 1) is exactly that the measurements are independent and identically distributed. Isn't that so or do we have different models in mind?

Comment: I didn't explicitly say that they are identically distributed, since OP doesn't seem super well versed in statistics and I wasn't sure how to put that in intuitive terms, like I did for independence. But I think I should just add that there, will edit the question.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your answer. Can you explain a bit more about this statement? `Also, we assumed that 3% is the standard deviation of the devices errors, but maybe this would mean that a given measurement would be within 3% of the true mean only ~62% of the time`? How is that different to your prior explanation of variance?

Comment: @Chuck sure. The thing is that when you say "I expect that each instrument will record the value to within 3% of the actual value.", that's a very vague statement, so I had to interpret what you meant in statistical terms in order to propose an answer. I chose to interpret it as 3% being the standard deviation of the measurements, which would mean that, for a normal distribution, 62% of the measurements would fall within 3% of the real value. If you meant "95% of the measures fall within 3%", then you'd want the standard deviation to be (3/2)%, and you'd work from there.

Comment: Please remember to mark as the accepted answer if it ends up being the one that answers your question.

Comment: I thoroughly appreciate the effort you have gone to answer the question. Thank you for explaining it. Let's just say this has been a learning experience for me.

Comment: @dherrera hey dude. I realise this isn't quite the answer to the question I was asking. Your answer is for measuring a known speed. But I don't know the speed that is being measured in advance. It could be anything between 20-50mph (as an example). 5 separate readings e.g. 35,38,37,37,36. Each with the 3%. Can you advise how this changes your answer? Would it be to take the mean? Then take sigma device as sigma mean? But presumably sigma device would be different for each device as they each measure a different value?

Comment: To get a statistical answer to a question, you need to formulate the question in the language of statistics. Your original question is vague and requires filling in the blanks, so I don't think it's possible to answer exactly the question you have in your mind if you don't narrow it down or give more precise language. Also, you don't seem aware that there's always subtelties to these problems, such as your question of "presumably sigma device would be different for each device as they each measure a different value?", which is a very important question indeed that I can't know the answer to

Comment: Evidently, there's things of your problem that you don't know, and so we have to approximate or assume them. We assume that the possible error of each device comes from the same underlying distribution (i.e. same variability), given a real speed. This is not an easy concept to wrap your head around if you're not used to statistics, but some approximation like this is necessary to approach the problem without more info. You seem to suggest that variability increases with real speed, because it's a percentage of real speed (i.e. 3%)

Comment: If what you want is the average to be withing a given % of the real speed, then the procedure in the question works fine. You just use the % as the $\sigma_{device}$ and the desired % as $\sigma_{mean}$ and use that formula. If you want an absolute value (i.e. errors should be smaller than 1 mph 99% of the times), you'll need to make a bunch of other assumptions and the problem becomes quite complicated. You can alternatively choose a reference real speed that is significant and just compute the N for that.